# Call Java Method from feature file

Tags: karate

I have a problem calling java method from feature file. I have few java methods in one class and only with this one I have a problem. I tried to move this method in another java.class but result is same.
This is error:

```
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
    >>>>
    01: result.generateOib()
    <<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (generateOib) on com.JavaMethod failed due to: Unknown identifier: generateOib
    - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

This is my java class

```
    public class JavaMethod {
    private static String generateOib() {
    List<Integer> tenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Random r = new Random();
    IntStream.range(0, 10).map(x -> r.nextInt(10)).forEach(tenNumbers::add);
    
    int oibZnamenka = 0;
    int zbroj = 0;
    int međuostatak = 0;
    int umnožak = 0;
    int ostatak = 0;
    int kontrolnaZnamenka = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tenNumbers.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
    oibZnamenka = tenNumbers.get(i) + 10;
    }
    oibZnamenka = ostatak + tenNumbers.get(i);
    zbroj = oibZnamenka % 10;
    if (zbroj == 0) {
    umnožak = 10 * 2;
    ostatak = umnožak % 11;
    } else {
    umnožak = zbroj * 2;
    ostatak = umnožak % 11;
    }
    if (i == 9) {
    kontrolnaZnamenka = 11 - ostatak;
    if (kontrolnaZnamenka == 10) {
    kontrolnaZnamenka = 0;
    }
    }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int num : tenNumbers) {
    sb.append(num);
    }
    sb.append(kontrolnaZnamenka);
    return sb.toString();
    }
    }
```

When I ran generateOib it works as expected, error occurs when call it from Background or Scenario.

This is my feature

```
    Scenario: Should generate oib
    * def result = Java.type('com.JavaMethod')
    * def oib = result.generateOib()
```

This is path from source root: com/JavaMethod.java
I couldn't find solution or answer for this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature is `private`. It needs to be `public`.